# How to choose a file in Android?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent, android-input-method, android-mediascanner

I use the code below to do the operation.

Intent action = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

```
    action = action.setType("*/*").addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(action, addEditInstance.INTENT_ATTACH_FILE);
```

But I get options to choose media files where i get result as

/external/images/media/92

but I am looking for only file names. Is there a way to get the actual file path from this uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope these code help. It's for image content URI, I guess other media types work as well

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String [] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,
                        proj, null, null, null);
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
```